# install 12.04 version of edubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows-xp, edubuntu

How can I change to edubuntu later version like 12.04 from existing edubuntu 10.04? my 10.04 version gives a message that gnome power manager not insatlled correctly.I cannot open my ubuntu os. My desktop has windows xp  os too.
                   Actually my edubuntu was showing an error mssage that gnome power manager not configured..As I tried to reinstall edubuntu from a  live cd (edubuntu 10.04) ..It asked me to select an option. I chose .. "Alongside another operating system".. after installing when I restarted  I cannot see grub boot menu..it simply boots into ubuntu. Where is my windows xp? Does it get accidentally erased or can I recover it again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [Edubuntu](http://www.edubuntu.org/) website, you will see that 10.04 users might be able to upgrade, although "sometimes" there are problems.  I would take this to mean that although there is an upgrade path, it may not work properly, ad a reinstall is a better solution.

The [Edubuntu download](http://www.edubuntu.org/download) page gives you the options needed to download an appropriate ISO file to burn onto a DVD, and install from there.  I would recommend that you backup all of your important files, both in Edubuntu and in Windows before you attempt to do either an upgrade or a new installation of Edubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Download the ISO and burn it to USB or DVD media and boot it. The installer will give you an option to update your system.

The caveat is that you will need to update to 11.10 first. You can read more about this in the [release notes for 12.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/Edubuntu#Upgrading_from_Other_Releases). The ISOs for the now unsupported 11.10 are [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/).